# How to print or log real executed query statements, such as django insert, query and other SQL statements will be logged

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

How to print or log real executed query statements, such as django insert, query and other SQL statements will be logged。I searched the documentation of both libraries and found nothing about this.

I want something similar to django in that I can execute any query such as `User.object.filter(name='123').values("id", "phone")` and log the actual execution statement of this query: `select id, phone from auth_user where name='123'`

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: if you are only inserted in listening to `Change` events and you happen to have a cluster i think [MongoDB ChangeStream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#change-streams) is there to help you out. Else for offline, you can look into [Mtools](https://github.com/rueckstiess/mtools).

Comment: `pymongo` has a handler to monitor queries: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/monitoring.html

Comment: @Peter As I've tried, monitor does listen for events, but it doesn't get executed queries

Comment: Do you use MongoDB or Relational Database? I ask this question because the question tags include `mongodb`, however you would like to get sql like query, but MongoDB has no sql like language support

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have 2 options:

1) use `pymongo.monitoring`, this [link](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/logging-monitoring.html#logging-monitoring) from MongoEngine's doc shows how to configure it.

2) Turn on Profiling with `db.setProfilingLevel(2)`, all queries will then be added to the `db.system.profile collection`.
E.g: executing this `db.users.findOne({'name': 'abc'})`, will add the following to the `db.system.profile` collection:

```
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "myDb.users",
    "command" : {
        "find" : "users",
        "filter" : {
            "name" : "abc"
        },
        "limit" : 1,
        ....
        "$db" : "myDb"
    },
    "keysExamined" : 0,
    "docsExamined" : 0,
    "cursorExhausted" : true,
    "numYield" : 0,
    "locks" : {...},
    "nreturned" : 0,
    "responseLength" : 83,
    "protocol" : "op_msg",
    "millis" : 0,
    "planSummary" : "EOF",
    ...
    "ts" : ISODate("2019-11-20T19:27:13.297Z"),
    "appName" : "MongoDB Shell",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

As you can see and unfortunately, its not as practical as a SQL query but the information is there